# Proving that the distance values extracted in Dijkstra's algorithm is non-decreasing?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, dijkstra, proof

I'm reviewing my old algorithms notes and have come across this proof.  It was from an assignment I had and I got it correct, but I feel that the proof certainly lacks.

The question is to `prove that the distance values taken from the priority queue in Dijkstra's algorithm is a non-decreasing sequence.`

My proof goes as follows:

> Proof by contradiction.  Fist, assume
>   that we pull a vertex from Q with
>   d-value 'i'.  Next time, we pull a
>   vertex with d-value 'j'.   When we
>   pulled i, we have finalised our
>   d-value and computed the shortest-path
>   from the start vertex, s, to i.  Since
>   we have positive edge weights, it is
>   impossible for our d-values to shrink
>   as we add vertices to our path. If
>   after pulling i from Q, we pull j with
>   a smaller d-value, we may not have a
>   shortest path to i, since we may be
>   able to reach i through j.  However,
>   we have already computed the shortest
>   path to i.  We did not check a
>   possible path.  We no longer have a
>   guaranteed path.  Contradiction.

How could this proof be improved upon?  Or better yet, is there a different approach?  It just seems pretty weak :)

**Edit:** Sorry, in this case my priority queue is implemented with a Min-heap

Comment: In the classic pseudocode implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm the Priority Queue implementation is not defined. No one has answered as it is hard to do the proof without the implementation (even in pseudo code) being used for the Priority Queue. Could you add a reference in the question?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated :)  Valid point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's establish these (these are all true, since they are, basically, the definition of the algorithm) :

> 1. The Priority Queue in Dijkstra's algorithm will give you the node with the lowest d-value in each iteration of the algorithm.
> 2. There are no negative edge weights.
> 3. Once a node has been dequeued, it will never return to the queue.
> 4. The d-value of a node that has been dequeued is final, and will not change from that point on.

Continuing (1), the d-value of that dequeued node, assuming (2) applies, will be at the very least equal to the previous d-value extracted, since each node's d-value depends on the d-values of the nodes dequeued prior to it, which is a sort of recursive definition. Since (3) and (4) are correct, this recursive definition ends at the starting node which has d-value of 0.
So, if each node's d-value is at the very least equal to the d-value before him, and (1) still applies, the set of d-values extracted from the priority queue is **non-decreasing**.

(After reading through this, and what you wrote, it's basically the same, but presented a bit better I think)